# Code coverage using ES6 + webpack + karma (aurelia framework)

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, aurelia, karma-coverage

I'm trying to setup code coverage in my project that uses ES6, Webpack 3 and Karma (it's based on Aurelia Framework). I use nyc to generate code coverage, but it seems to not working properly. I can see code coverage only for couple files:

[image]

Normally I run unit tests by command `npm test` and I try to run coverage by command `npm run test-cov`. These commands look like:

```
`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start",
"test-cov": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc karma start karma.conf.js"
`
```

I added to `karma.conf.js` required codes:

```
`preprocessors: {
    'build/bundle.js': ['webpack'],
    'test/**/*.js': ['webpack'],
    'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
}`
```

and:

```
`reporters: ['progress', 'coverage']`
```

I also use the `istanbul` plugin and I init it in webpack configuration file like this:

```
`{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: [
        /node_modules/,
        /src\/app-config/
    ],
    options: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [
            ['es2015', { loose: true }],
            'stage-1'
        ],
        env: {
            test: {
                plugins: ['istanbul']
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-runtime'
        ]
    }
}`
```

I spent on this issue many hours and I don't know what to do next. I'll appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any luck with this? Have you tried it with the new cli and updated modules?